# Continuous CABasicAnimation independent of parent layer animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am unable to figure out if it is possible to execute a CABasicAnimation independently of possible super view animations.

Let's say I want to have a continuous spinning sub view:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

[rotation setFromValue:@(0.0)];
[rotation setToValue:@(2.0 * M_PI)];
[rotation setDuration:2.0];
[rotation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];

[[_rotatingView layer] addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Rotate"];
```

This works. The problem is that in some super view upwards the view chain the speed and time offset of the layer of that view is used to manually control some animations.

This automatically controls this rotation animation. I would like this rotation animation (at least the timing part of it) to run independently and not be influenced by possible animations up the view chain.

Is this possible?